# How do you dynamically hide form fields in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making a profile form in Django. There are a lot of optional extra profile fields but I would only like to show two at a time. How do I hide or remove the fields I do not want to show dynamically?

Here is what I have so far:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
    extra_field_total = 2

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra_field_count = 0
        for key, field in self.base_fields.iteritems():
            if key in self.extra_fields:
                if extra_field_count < self.extra_field_total:
                    extra_field_count += 1
                else:
                    # do something here to hide or remove field
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1914812/462865

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think I found my answer.

First I tried:

```
field.widget = field.hidden_widget
```

which didn't work.

The correct way happens to be:

```
field.widget = field.hidden_widget()
```

Comment: what if you have an invalid value in the hidden field? you users will go nuts...

Answer (score 4):

Can also use

```
def __init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):    
    super(FormClass, self).__init__(instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)
    if instance and instance.item:
        del self.fields['field_for_item']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_video = kwargs.pop('is_video')
    is_image = kwargs.pop('is_image')
    super(ContestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_video:
        del self.fields['video_link']
        # self.exclude('video_link')
    if is_image:
        del self.fields['image']
```

use `delete` instead of `self.exclude()`.

Comment: Why `del` is better than `self.exclude()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are coding this in the Form. Wouldn't it make more sense to do this using CSS and JavaScript in the template code? Hiding a field is as easy as setting "display='none'" and toggling it back to 'block', say, if you need to display it.

Maybe some context on what the requirement is would clarify this.

Comment: Firstly, just because I think form logic should stay in the form. Also, because I see what fields have already been filled out before and don't show those.

Comment: This moves business logic into the presentation layer ("these objects don't have this field").  Especially bad if the web developer is NOT the backend developer.

Comment: what if a value in a hidden field is not valid (any more)? you'll get "please correct the errors below"...happy searching.