# Limiting fields in admin by usergroup

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to give different usergroups access to the Admin portion of my Django site and control which fields they are able to access. I plan on doing this with a custom `ModelAdmin` object that decides what to add to the `fieldsets` property based on the current user's group memberships.

- Is this secure (i.e., if a field is not displayed, and the admin uses firebug or something to change the form, will Django stop it)?
- Is this the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is secure as it is processed server side. I don't know about `fieldsets`. You could solve it by using `get_form`. E.g (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6272877/538471)):

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    current_user = request.user
    if not current_user.profile.is_manager:
        self.exclude = ('added_by',)
        self.list_display = ('name', 'finish')
    form = super(MovieAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.current_user = current_user
    return form
```