# Django custom forms for Admin deleting fields dynamically

Tags: django, forms, admin

The problem is I have a model called Gift. And it has a boolean field 'giftbought' that I want to hide in admin interface when the object is being created and show it when it is being updated.

I tryed making a form, overriding **init** method like:

```
class GiftForm(forms.ModelForm):
    giftbought = forms.BooleanField(label=u"Bought?", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Gift

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GiftForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.instance.pk:
            del self.fields['giftbought']
```

But it doesn't work for admin, like it is being said in:
[Remove fields from ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466512/remove-fields-from-modelform)

I thing I needed to make a class ModelAdmin, overriding get_form method, but I don't know how to check if I is_instance or not...

It would be something like:

```
class GiftAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Gift

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # that IF doesnt work!!!
        if not self.instance.pk:
            self.exclude = ('giftbought',)
        return super(GiftAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Gift, GiftAdmin)
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely your best bet is `ModelAdmin`. I think you got it right except for the `if` test.

You should be able to do it like this:

```
class GiftAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Gift

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.exclude = []
        # self.instance.pk should be None if the object hasn't yet been persisted
        if obj is None:
            self.exclude.append('giftbought')
        return super(GiftAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Gift, GiftAdmin)
```

Notice there are minor changes to the method code. You should [check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form), I'm sure you'll find everything you need there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Paulo.. I tried that, and both inserting and updating, I get the error: 'GiftAdmin' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: It makes sense, how about the way you got it first? self.instance.pk?

Comment: It worked just changing to "if obj is None"! self.instance doesn't exist either.

Comment: I see, great, I'll modify the answer.