# Django hide a fake field in a modelform

Tags: django, modelform

I have a ModelForm with some fake fields that I process later when save the model.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field1= forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    field2= forms.ChoiceField(choices=SIDES_CHOICES, required=True)
    field3= forms.CharField(max_length=140, required=False)
```

What I need is to show or to hide some of them depending on whether we are adding a new instance or changing an existing one.

All I read is about hide real fields that are defined in the model, but it's not my case. With 'fake' i mean fields that are not in the model or database, only defined in the form.

I have tried this in the `__init__` override of the ModelForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.instance.pk:
        del self.fields['field1']
```

But I get this error:

```
Key 'field1' not found in 'MyForm'
```

Entire error traceback:

```
Template error:
In template C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django_suit-0.2.18-py3.4.egg\suit\templates\admin\change_form.html, error at line 19
   Key 'field1' not found in 'MyForm'   9 :   {{ media }}
   10 : 
   11 : {% endblock %}
   12 : 
   13 : 
   14 : {% block extrajs %}
   15 :   {{ block.super }}
   16 : 
   17 :   {% if 'CONFIRM_UNSAVED_CHANGES'|suit_conf %}
   18 :     <!-- Warn on leaving unsaved form -->
   19 :     <script src="{% static  'suit/js/suit-form- confirm.js' %}"></script>
   20 :     <script type="text/javascript">
   21 :       confirmExitIfModified('{% firstof opts.model_name opts.module_name %}_form', '{% trans 'You have unsaved changes' %}.');
   22 :     </script>
   23 :   {% endif %}
   24 : 
   25 :   {% if adminform.model_admin.suit_form_tabs %}
   26 :     <script type="text/javascript">
   27 :     (function ($) {
   28 :       $(function () {
   29 :         $('#suit_form_tabs').suit_form_tabs();


Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in __getitem__
  141.             field = self.fields[name]

During handling of the above exception ('field1'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  1043.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  709.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  850.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  913.                             current = current()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in super
  83.             return mark_safe(self.render(self.context))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  209.                 return template.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  584.             return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  319.                     match = condition.eval(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py" in eval
  951.         return self.value.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  709.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  850.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  913.                             current = current()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py" in errors
  117.             for f in self.fields if f not in self.readonly_fields).strip('\n')

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py" in <genexpr>
  117.             for f in self.fields if f not in self.readonly_fields).strip('\n')

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in __getitem__
  144.                 "Key %r not found in '%s'" % (name, self.__class__.__name__))
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information. What is a "fake field" and how does it differ from a real field? How are you defining those fields in the first place?

Comment: Before or after calling `super()`?

Comment: Sorry for my short question. I have already edited. Fake field is a field that is only in the form, not in the model or database table. What I tried is after super().

Comment: Add the extra fields to the `fields` list in the `Meta` class.

Comment: @evergreen They are already in it, but I delete what I don't want to be shown in the `__init__` method, and it seems django doesn't like this...

Comment: If you comment out the line  `del self.fields['field1']`, do all of the fields appear in the form?

Comment: @evergreen yes, all of them

Comment: If you add `for f in self.fields:` and `print(f + '\n')` does it list the "fake" fields?

Comment: Yes, they are there. If I delete on of the fake fields it is deleted without problems from the dict, but after this, django server crashes

Comment: Try going back to your original code and try `del self.fields['field2']` Does that work? If the fields are in the dict, then `del` shouldn't give you a key error.

Comment: `del`doesn't give me any error. the error comes later when load the form in the browser

Comment: Okay. I think I finally understand. Somewhere in your ModelForm code you are probably referencing `field1` after you have already removed it from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `field1` from the form in `__init__` if the form is used for a new instance of the model. The key error means that at least one place in your ModelForm code is referencing `field1` after you have already removed it (for a new instance). If the error traceback doesn't point you to the line that's generating the error, just search your code for occurrences of `field1` and make sure that you're testing for a new instance before you execute each of those sections of code.

**Edit**
Since the form is being used as an AdminForm, Comment out the lines in the ModelForm where you delete `field1` and add the following to your ModelAdmin, based on an answer to [Remove fields from ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466512/remove-fields-from-modelform):

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)
    if not obj:
        self.exclude = ['field1',]
    return form
```

Comment: The error comes from this line:
`C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.6-py3.4.egg\django\forms\forms.py in __getitem__, line 144` I am not referencing this field (consciously) in any other part of my code.

Comment: Can you please post the entire error traceback? You can just edit your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Done!

Comment: The error is apparently from the admin. Are there any references to `field1` in your ModelAdmin?

Comment: No one. These fields must not be shown in the changelist, and I don't have any other list of fields but list_display. In list_display I just have fields from the model.