# How to initialize django-form data type field from a given choices?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

First of all: I am not able to find out the proper Title of this question.

Anyhow the question is:

I have to fill a form at template and the fields of this form are user dependent. For example you passes `integer` (integer is not a datatype) as a parameter to the method and it should returns like this:

```
fileds = forms.IntegerField()
```

If you pass `bool` then it should like this:

```
fields = forms.BooleanField()
```

So that i can use them to create my form. I tried with this code but it returns into the form of string.

Some.py file:

```
choices = (('bool','BooleanField()'),
            ('integer','IntegerField()'))
def choose_field():
   option = 'bool' # Here it is hardcoded but in my app it comes from database.
   for x in choices:
      if x[0]==option:
         type = x[1]
   a = 'forms'
   field = [a,type]
   field = ".".join(field)
   return field
```

When i print the field it prints `'forms.BooleanField()'`. I also use this return value but it didn't work. Amy solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not `type = dict(choices)[option]`? (And you probably run unnecessary `eval` somewhere later instead of `getattr`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way is to create your form class and include fields for all possible choices to it. Then write a constructor in this class and [hide the fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255976/how-do-you-dynamically-hide-form-fields-in-django) you don't want to appear. The constructor must take a parameter indicating which fields do we need. It can be useful to store this parameter in the form and use it in `clean` method to correct collected data accordingly to this parameter.

```
class Your_form(forms.ModelForm):
  field_integer = forms.IntegerField()
  field_boolean = forms.BooleanField()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    option = kwargs["option"]
    if option == "integer":
      field_boolean.widget = field_boolean.hidden_widget()
    else:
      field_integer.widget = field_integer.hidden_widget()
    super(Your_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your controller:

```
option = 'bool'
form = Your_form(option=option)
```

Comment: But i don't have extra field like the question (you gave me a link). I want to create a new field and the data type to that field is the value of option variable. In my app when user is registering him. He enter a option value which save in his user profile model. So the ***option*** is that value.

Comment: And you are saying to include all the fields. I just gave a example, in actual all field is available in choices. So i can't choose that option. :(

Comment: Create separate field for each type. One integer field, one boolean field etc.

Comment: I am newbie in Django. Would you please give me the basic code?